# what ground cover to use under bike storage shelter?

Tags: flooring, shed, storage

I recently built a lean-to style bike shelter in the yard; no walls, with a sloping roof, and big enough for 4 or 5 bikes.

At the moment it's bare earth on the ground, does anyone have any suggestions for ground cover? I can't pour concrete because of my city's bylaws and the bikes have to be able to stand up with their kickstands.

Thanks!

phanmo

Answer (score 4):

Are you able to put down bricks or cobblestones?  Or Pre-cast concrete pavers?

Ideally you want a hard surface that won't be muddy in the rain, and will allow rainwater to drain off.  It should therefore stand slightly higher than the nearest drain.

Bicycles aren't heavy, but you still want a flat base layer of compacted sand to support the pavers/bricks, to prevent them moving and cracking.  The base layer would need to resist washing out in rain too.   A good base layer helps keep all your pavers/bricks level to prevent trip hazard.

Lastly, you will want some way to lock up your bikes too, which probably means some kind of hasp or loop or shackle to secure your bike's lock.  I'd also put hooks in the inside for things like helmets and wet coats.